# ajax response return page html, when load from modal popup

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, codeigniter

My scenario is add value to textField when dropdown change, now I use ajax and json and I use cibonfire HMVC framework, this my code.

```
/* get airline and unit */
    $('select[name="item"]').change(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'reg_inv_penjualan/getAirlineAndUnit',
            type:'POST',
            data: ({ 
                ci_csrf_token: $("input[name=ci_csrf_token]").val(),
                id: $(this).val()
            }),
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                aData = eval(data);
                console.log(aData);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log( JSON.stringify(error) );
            }
        });

    });
```

this is my method to return json use json_encode;

```
/**
 * method:
 * @return: json
 */
function getAirlineAndUnit() {
    $this->output->set_header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $data = $this->reg_inv_penjualan_model->getAirlineAndUnit($id);
    die(json_encode($data));
}
```

this my image: 
[image]

when dropdownlist item change, Airline textfield will get value.

thanks.

this the return error:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\r\n<div class=\"row-fluid\">\r\n\t<ul class=\"nav nav-tabs\">\r\n\t\t<li>\r\n\t\t\t<a href=\"http://localhost/stam/admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/tiket/reg_inv_penjualan\">Tiket</a>\r\n\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t<li>\r\n\t\t\t<a href=\"http://localhost/stam/admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/hotel/reg_inv_penjualan\">Hotel</a>\r\n\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t<li>\r\n\t\t\t<a href=\"http://localhost/stam/admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/tour/reg_inv_penjualan\">Tour</a>\r\n\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t<li>\r\n\t\t\t<a href=\"http://localhost/stam/admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/dokumen/reg_inv_penjualan\">Dokumen</a>\r\n\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t<li>\r\n\t\t\t<a href=\"http://localhost/stam/admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/trans/reg_inv_penjualan\">Transportasi</a>\r\n\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t<li>\r\n\t\t\t<a href=\"http://localhost/stam/admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/haji/reg_inv_penjualan\">Haji</a>\r\n\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t<li>\r\n\t\t\t<a href=\"http://localhost/stam/admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/umroh/reg_inv_penjualan\">Umroh</a>\r\n\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t<li>\r\n\t\t\t<a href=\"http://localhost/stam/admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/other/reg_inv_penjualan\">Other</a>\r\n\t\t</li>\r\n\t</ul>\r\n\t\r\n<div class=\"row-fluid\">\r\n\t<div class=\"pull-right\">\r\n\t\t<button id=\"btnAddTiket\" class=\"btn btn-success pull-righ\" ><i class=\"icon-plus\"></i>&nbsp;Add Item</button>\r\n\t</div>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<hr />\r\n\r\n<div class=\"row-fluid\">\r\n\t<table id=\"tblInvItemTiket\" class=\"table table-striped dataTable\">\r\n\t\t<thead>\r\n\t\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t<th>No. Booking</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t<th>Maskapai/Airline</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t<th>No. Penerbangan</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t<th>Penumpang</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t<th>Pax Paid</th>\r\n\t\t\t</tr>\r\n\t\t</thead>\r\n\t\t<tbody></tbody>\r\n\t\t<tfoot></tfoot>\r\n\t</table>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<!-- Modal -->\r\n<div id=\"myModal\" class=\"modal hide fade\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"myModalLabel\" aria-hidden=\"true\" style=\"width:800px;margin-left:-400px;\">\r\n\t<form class=\"form-horizontal cmxform\" id=\"formTiket\" method=\"get\" action=\"\">\r\n\t\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ci_csrf_token\" value=\"c0d97bdcf095acff1bdc7efa1b488efb\" />\n\t<div class=\"modal-header\">\r\n\t\t<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>\r\n\t\t<h3 id=\"myModalLabel\">Add Item</h3>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t\r\n\t<div class=\"modal-body\">\r\n\t\t<div class=\"admin-box\">\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t<fieldset>\r\n\t\t\t\t<legend>Tiket Pesawat</legend>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<!-- item -->\r\n\t\t\t\t\n<div class=\"control-group \">\n\t<label class=\"control-label\" for=\"item\">Item</label>\n\t<div class=\"controls\">\n\t\t <select name=\"item\"  class=\"span9\">\n\t\t\t<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">--pilih--</option>\n<option value=\"1\">AA&nbsp;-&nbsp;American Airline</option>\n<option value=\"2\">AG&nbsp;-&nbsp;Provincial Airline</option>\n\n\t\t</select>\n\t\t\n\t</div>\n</div>\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<!-- airline -->\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"airline\" class=\"control-label\">Airline</label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"airline\" type=\"text\" name=\"airline\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<!-- unit -->\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"unit\" class=\"control-label\">Unit</label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"unit\" type=\"text\" name=\"unit\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t</fieldset>\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t<fieldset>\r\n\t\t\t\t<legend>Rute</legend>\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"no_flight\" class=\"control-label\">Flight No.<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"no_flight\" type=\"text\" name=\"no_flight\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"no_tiket\" class=\"control-label\">Tiket No.<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"no_tiket\" type=\"text\" name=\"no_tiket\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"from\" class=\"control-label\">From<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"from\" type=\"text\" name=\"from\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">To<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"to\" type=\"text\" name=\"to\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Class<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"class\" type=\"text\" name=\"class\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Depature Date<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"depature\" type=\"text\" name=\"depature\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">ETD<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"etd\" type=\"text\" name=\"etd\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Arrival Date<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"arrival\" type=\"text\" name=\"arrival\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">ETA<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"eta\" type=\"text\" name=\"eta\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Status<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"status\" type=\"text\" name=\"status\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Booking No.<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"no_booking\" type=\"text\" name=\"no_booking\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t</fieldset>\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t<fieldset>\r\n\t\t\t\t<legend>Selling</legend>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Basic Fare<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"basic_fare\" type=\"text\" name=\"basic_fare\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Ppn<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"ppn\" type=\"text\" name=\"ppn\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">IWJR<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"iwjr\" type=\"text\" name=\"iwjr\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">surcharge<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"surcharge\" type=\"text\" name=\"surcharge\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Surevice Fee<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"service_fee\" type=\"text\" name=\"service_fee\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Potongan Tunai<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"potongan_tunai\" type=\"text\" name=\"potongan_tunai\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Total Pax Paid<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"total_pax_paid\" type=\"text\" name=\"total_pax_paid\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t</fieldset>\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t<fieldset>\r\n\t\t\t\t<legend></legend>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Gross Profit<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"gross_profit\" type=\"text\" name=\"gross_profit\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Supplier<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<div style=\"margin-bottom:10px;\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<input type=\"radio\" name=\"supplier\" />Deposit\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<input type=\"radio\" name=\"supplier\" />Supplier\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"supplier\" type=\"text\" name=\"supplier\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Nama Penumpang<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"nama_penumpang\" type=\"text\" name=\"nama_penumpang\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">No. Telepon<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"no_telepon\" type=\"text\" name=\"no_telepon\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Email<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input id=\"email\" type=\"text\" name=\"email\" class=\"span9\" maxlength=\"30\" />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"control-group \">\r\n\t\t\t\t<label for=\"to\" class=\"control-label\">Remark<span class=\"required\">*</span></label>\t\t\t\t\t<div class='controls'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<textarea name=\"remark\" cols=\"40\" rows=\"5\" id=\"remark\" class=\"span9\" ></textarea>\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"help-inline\"></span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t</fieldset>\r\n\t\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t\r\n\t<div class=\"modal-footer\">\r\n\t\t<button class=\"btn\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\">Close</button>\r\n\t\t<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" value=\"Save Tiket\" />\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t\r\n\t</form></div>\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

and this is my page code:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . 'admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/tiket/' . $id ?>">Tiket</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . 'admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/hotel/' . $id ?>">Hotel</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . 'admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/tour/' . $id ?>">Tour</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . 'admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/dokumen/' . $id ?>">Dokumen</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . 'admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/trans/' . $id ?>">Transportasi</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . 'admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/haji/' . $id ?>">Haji</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . 'admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/umroh/' . $id ?>">Umroh</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . 'admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/add_item/other/' . $id ?>">Other</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

<?php if (isset($item)) :?>
<?php 
    switch ($item) {
            case 'tiket':
                $this->load->view('invoicing/tiket', $dataItem);
            break;

            case 'hotel':
                $this->load->view('invoicing/hotel');
            break;

            case 'tour':
                $this->load->view();
            break;

            case 'dokumen':
                $this->load->view();
            break;

            case 'trans':
                $this->load->view();
            break;

            case 'other':
                $this->load->view();
            break;

            case 'haji':
                $this->load->view();
            break;

            case 'umroh':
                $this->load->view();
            break;
        }
?>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

switch position is tiket.

and this my model code:

```
/**
 * method: populate Airline and Unit
 * 
 */
function getAirlineAndUnit($id) {
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('data_airline.nama, data_item.unit');
    $this->db->from('data_item');
    $this->db->join('data_airline', 'data_airline.id = data_item.id');
    $this->db->where('data_item.id', $id);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $q->row_array();
        $data[] = array('nama_airline'=>$row['nama'], 'unit'=>$row['unit']);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Ditch that `eval` statement, jQuery takes care of processing the JSON for you. What's your console.log statement produce? Also, post the HTML for the element you wish to modify.

Comment: the console.log from error give back html code from my page.

Comment: Check your console under the Network tab, what is the error on the request?

Comment: I don't have network error on the network tab.

Comment: Is the status of the request 200 OK?

Comment: yes it is. but I don't have json tab from request.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way to solve this problem, the problem is ajax URL not correct because I use Assets::add_js($inline, 'inline'); on the tiket page. so URL always return wrong.
I move the code to view folder use name js.php and load to view on controller. this the code:

```
/* get airline and unit */
$('select[name="item"]').change(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(). 'admin/invoicing/reg_inv_penjualan/getAirlineAndUnit' ?>',
        type:'POST',
        data: ({ 
            ci_csrf_token: $("input[name=ci_csrf_token]").val(),
            id: $(this).val()
        }),
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            aData = eval(data);

        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log( JSON.stringify(error) );
        }
    });

});
```

and if you wan load base_url on ajax use '/' in the first URL.

thanks.